# Cardinality of set of all straight lines in $\mathbb R^2$, that pass through at least two different rational coordinates.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

**Definition:** A coordinate $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$ is rational if $x,y$ are both rational nos. 
Let $S$ be the set of all straight lines in $\mathbb R^2$ that pass through at least two distinct rational points.

Let $C$ be the set of all rational points in $\mathbb R^2$. Since $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$ is countable so are its subsets. Therefore, it is possible to write  $C=\{c_1,c_2,...,c_k,c_{k+1},...\}$. Of course $C=\mathbb Q \times \mathbb 
 Q$.

Let $S_i$ be the set of all straight lines that pass through $c_i\in C$. For every $s\in S_i$, $\exists$ a rational point $c_{k(s)}\ne c_i$ thus we can have a bijection. Therefore, $S_i$ is countable.

Hence, $S=\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} S_i$ is countable collection of countable sets and therefore countable.

Is my proof correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but not completely:

1. The set $S_i$, as defined, is not countable. In order to be countable, the set $S_i$ should be defined as the set of lines **in $S$**, tha passes through $c_i$.
2. also, with this definition, $S_i$ the described map is not a bijection. It is true that there is a map from $C$ to $S_i$ that assigns to $c_j$ the line passing through $c_i$ and $c_j$. But this map is not a bijection (it is not injective): Still, it is surjective. This implies that $S_i$ is countable.

Last step of the proof is now correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :). 1. Noted. 2. Let $s\in S_1$ be a straight line passing through $c_i$ and hence by given condition we can choose $c_{ij(s)}\ne c_i$ such that $s$ passes through it. We form $C_i=\cup_{s\in S_i}\{c_{ij(s)}\}$. We define $f: S_i\to C_i$ as $f(s)=c_{ij(s)}$. $f$ is injective and onto as well. Isn't it?

Comment: Well, the fact is that your $c_{ij(s)}$ is not unique, given $s \in S_1$ and $c_i\in S$, there are infinitely many such $c_{ij(s)}$. You can choose one of course, and form the set $C_i$. But you should proove that you can make the choice in a injective way, that goes down to proof that $S_i$ is countable. And basically *the* way to do it is to build a surjective function from $C$ to $S_i$.

Comment: The introduction of sets $C_i$ is just a not useful complication in the argument.

Comment: You are right that there may be many choices for $c_{ij(s)}$ but I can pick one using Axiom of choice. After that, for another straight line $t\in S_i$, it is possible to choose $c_{it(s)}$ different from $c_{ij(s)}$ because if not then $s$ and $t$ are the same! (Two points define a unique line). That was the idea. But I got your point:  my $C_i$ and $f$ needed a little explanation here.

Comment: If $f:C\to S_i$ is the map that assigns to $c_j$ the line through $c_i$ and $c_j$, what you are doing is consctructc a left inverse of $f$. But you don't need it, because the existence of $f$, which is onto, gives you the countability of $S_i$, as desired. You can construct a left inverse, if you like, but this is just unnecessary extra work.

Comment: I understand that you are defining mapping from C to $S_i$. Alternatively, it would be safe to say that the mapping $f:S_i\to C_i$ as I have defined will be "atleast" injective and therefore $S_i$ is at most countable. Is that argument correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your primary question "Is my proof correct?" has been answered by
user $7\cdot 9011\cdot 2\,$.
The ensuing comment-discussion hints at some detour in your proof.

You may directly aim at a bijection by observing that an element in $S$ is either

- parallel to the $y$-axis, hence a vertical line having a rational $\,x_0\,$ as $x$-intercept,
- or both its slope $\,m\,$ and its $y$-intercept $\,y_0\,$ are rational.

Taken together, these correspondences define a bijection
$$S\:\longrightarrow\:\big(\{\perp\}\times\mathbb Q\big)\cup\big(\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q\big)
\:=\: \big(\{\perp\}\cup\mathbb Q\big)\times\mathbb Q\,$$
whose range set is countably infinite.
With the symbol $\perp\,$ standing for "vertical line", and the variable $\,m\in\mathbb Q\,$ as slope we have
$$\big\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2 \mid x=x_0\big\}\;\longmapsto\;(\perp, x_0)\\[3ex]
\big\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2 \mid y=mx+y_0\big\}\;\longmapsto\;(m, y_0)\,.$$

Comment: :) +1 Thanks a lot. I understood. The bijection $f:S\to \big( \{v\}\cup\mathbb Q\big)\times\mathbb Q$ can be defined by: $f(s)= (r_x, y)$ if straight line $s$ is parallel to $y-$ axis. (for every straight line $x=r_x$, we can choose one rational no. $y$ on it) and $f(s)=(m,c)$, if not parallel to $y-$ axis, where $m, c$ are slope of straight line and $y-$ intercept respectively.

Comment: @Koro In principle, yes. $v$ like 'vertical', not like 'variable', has been introduced as  a marker/symbol. I shall edit to make the intended correspondence more precise.